# Преобразовать в JS

Tags: javascript, php

Есть некоторая функция определения времени на PHP, помогите преобразовать в JS

```
function getTime($time = 0) {
$monthes = array("Января", "Февраля", "Марта", "Апреля", "Мая", "Июня", "Июля", "Августа", "Сентября", "Октября", "Ноября", "Декабря");
if ($time) {
    $shift = time() - $time;
    if ($shift < 10)
        return 'Только что';
    elseif ($shift < 60)
        return plural($shift,array('секунду','секунды','секунд','секунда')).' назад';
    elseif ($shift < 3600)
        return  plural(floor($shift / 60),array('минуту','минуты','минут','минута')).' назад';
    elseif (date('d') == date('d', $time) && date('n Y') == date('n Y', $time))
        return 'Сегодня в ' . date('H:i', $time);
    elseif (date('d') - 1 == date('d', $time) && date('n Y') == date('n Y', $time))
        return 'Вчера в ' . date('H:i', $time);
    elseif (date('Y') == date('Y', $time))
        return date('j', $time) . ' ' . $monthes[date('n', $time) - 1] . ' в ' . date('H:i', $time);
    elseif (date('Y') != date('Y', $time))
        return date('j', $time) . ' ' . $monthes[date('n', $time) - 1] . ' ' . date('Y', $time) . ' в ' . date('H:i', $time);
}
else
    return date('H:i:s');
```

}

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: Меня интересует тоже вопрос, что не получается. Я пока обживаюсь на ХэшКоде, но я так понимаю вопрос подпадает в категорию - "сделайте за меня", что есть моветон, если я все правильно понял в сдешних устоях.

Comment: Ну основная трабла будет с аналогом date, т.к. в JS с датами менее удобно работать. А так код почти идентичный будет